# Cannot answer protected questions on iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, protected-questions

The **answer** button for protected questions are gone.

For example, take a look at [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/209866/79435) question. The question is very good and its quality is high, but the answer is relatively bad. Although I want to answer a better one, I can't answer it on the iOS app because of the bug. I can just go to SE full site with Chrome or Safari, but it is quite inconvenient.

[image: !]

[image: !]

Using iOS SEß 1.2.2.202.

Comment: Note to anyone who has this thought: The asker has 935 rep on that site, so should be able to answer protected questions (this isn't a case of the 100 association bonus not letting them answer protected things).

Comment: If you can post a screenshot that would be more helpful to others

Comment: @cpast true, the bug is that the iOS app (or the API itself) is not reading the user actual privileges properly for some reason.